# Programa en C no suma bien los elementos de un vector

Tags: c, array

Estoy realizando un programa básico en C, para calcular notas. 
Consiste en un array en el que se almacenan unas notas leídas por teclado. Una ve se introducen, se suman una a una y se guardan en una variable.

El problema está en que no suma los elementos del vector, solamente guarda el último en la variable. Dejo el código:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {

int i = 0, j, sino, porcentaje, cont = 0;
float notas[10], total = 0, notaActual;

do {
  printf("Escribe la nota: ");
  scanf("%f", &notaActual);

  printf("Escribe el porcentaje sobre 100 de esa nota sobre la nota total: ");
  scanf("%d", &porcentaje);

  notas[i] = notaActual*(porcentaje*0.01);

  printf("Continuar con las notas? (1/0): ");
  scanf("%d", &sino);

  if(sino == 1)
    i++;

} while (sino == 1 && i < 10); //No es necesario llenar el vector

for(j = 0; j <= i; j++) {
  total += notas[j];
  printf("%f ", notas[j]);
}

printf("\nTU NOTA SOBRE 10 ES %f", &total);

return 0;
}
```

Si introducimos un 5 con porcentaje 50 en dos iteraciones, la salida es:

```
2.50 2.50

TU NOTA SOBRE 10 ES 2.50
```

Comment: En la última línea imprimo la variable total, que es la suma de los elementos del vector.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo que le falla a tu código es que el método `printf` final no necesita el & para apuntar a la variable. Es decir, tu código queda así:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {

int i = 0, j, sino, porcentaje, cont = 0;
float notas[10], total = 0.0, notaActual;

do {
  printf("Escribe la nota: ");
  scanf("%f", &notaActual);

  printf("Escribe el porcentaje sobre 100 de esa nota sobre la nota total: ");
  scanf("%d", &porcentaje);

  notas[i] = notaActual*(porcentaje*0.01);

  printf("Continuar con las notas? (1/0): ");
  scanf("%d", &sino);

  if(sino == 1)
    i++;

} while (sino == 1 && i < 10); //No es necesario llenar el vector

for(j = 0; j <= i; j++) {
  total += notas[j];
  printf("%f ", notas[j]);
}

printf("\nTU NOTA SOBRE 10 ES %f", total);

return 0;
}
```